# clearIntervall don't stop scrolling set with timer

Tags: javascript

I'm a js newbie but from what I read, using `clearInterval` with id returned previously by `setInterval` should reset the timer.

On a pedal push I receive a midi event with a positive value and then same event with a zero value on pedal release.
Using the code below, I can see my page turning red on release but the page keeps scrolling. Any idea why ?

```js
function handleMIDIMessage(event) {
  var scroll_id;
  if (event.data.length === 3) {
    if (event.data[0] == 176 && event.data[1] === 67) {
      if (event.data[2] > 0) {
        scroll_id = setInterval(function() {
          window.scrollBy({
            top: 50,
            behaviour: "smooth"
          });
        }, 1000);
        document.body.style.background = 'green';
      } else {
        document.body.style.background = 'red';
        clearInterval(scroll_id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: probably creating multiple intervals and a local variable so you loose track of the interval since you clear it otu.

Comment: Every `setInterval` needs to be cleared, eventually. If you do `let x; x = setInterval(`…`); x = setInterval(`…`); clearInterval(x);`, then you initiate two intervals, clear the second one, while the first one is no longer reachable. Consider using `clearInterval` before `setInterval`.

Comment: It's probably the difference in the time of the release and the setInterval events firing and running.  In other words, 1. you release the pedal 2. there are still setInterval events queued and they run _after_ the pedal is released.  This is a guess.

Comment: Adding to what @epascarello said, every time you are running this function you are creating a new value of the interval Id. Your use case might require you to have the ID as global

Comment: What @TusharShahi says is correct. As the variable is local in the function, the values doesn't persist until you call the function the next time. Move the declaration of the variable outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the interval outside so you do not keep creating a new variable and losing the id. You should probably also check to make sure you are not creating more than one interval.

```
//declare it so it is not overwritten
var scroll_id;
function handleMIDIMessage(event) {

  if (event.data.length === 3) {
    if (event.data[0] == 176 && event.data[1] === 67) {
      if (event.data[2] > 0) {
        // if we were defined before, cancel the last one
        if (scroll_id) window.clearInterval(scroll_id);
        scroll_id = setInterval(function() {
          window.scrollBy({
            top: 50,
            behaviour: "smooth"
          });
        }, 1000);
        document.body.style.background = 'green';
      } else {
        document.body.style.background = 'red';
        clearInterval(scroll_id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```